# A basic function that doesn't work

Tags: ksh, function

I've tried several modifications to see why it's not working, but I can't find the answer.

Here is my code, this is in french but this is just a normal fonction that ask to the user if he's ready to start.

```
#!/bin/ksh
function start 
{
    echo "Vous etes sur le point de lancer la generation, etes-vous pret(e)? [OUI/NON]"
    read touche
    case $touche in
        [Oo] | [Oo][Uu][Ii] )   
        echo "Demarage du bash..."
        ;;
        [Nn] | [Nn][Oo][Nn] )
        echo "Annulation du bash..."
        exit
        ;;
    esac
}
start
```

This is what I get :

```
  sh start.sh
  : unfindable command
  »art.sh: line 3: syntax error close to the « symbol
  'tart.sh: line 3: `function start
```

Comment: try setting #!/bin/ksh in the beginning of the script.

Comment: Already done :)

Comment: check your file if it is saved in dos format and convert it to unix format.

Comment: I think you run on AIX and version of ksh is lower.

Comment: the spaces in your case patterns are not ok - and some shells *(definitely `zsh` which is based on old `ksh` code)* get upset when those patterns don't open with a leading `(`.

Comment: @taliezin, you don't need the `#!` line if you start the script as the OP did with explicitly calling `sh`. @mikeserv, you don't need the `(` in the case pattern; also in old ksh's, and also in the SUS/POSIX standards, this is standard syntax, and was defined that way since bourne shell.

Comment: @Janis, sorry I think in the first post it was not there or I missed it. Sorry.

Comment: Ouch, don't try to translate error messages back into English. Run your script in an English locale: `LC_ALL=C start.sh`, and you'll find that “commande introuvable” is a translation for “command not found”, which is recognizable and googlable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My file was saved in DOS Format, I used dos2unix start.sh to convert it.